# How to find a way to resist full mind control

Tags: mind-control, control, supervillain

In my story, there's an overturned villain. He used to be a pizza delivery guy, but one day delivering one of his pizzas, he enters an empty nuclear zone. It appears that a super intelligent organism has managed to escape and called the pizza guy as a host to transmit to. My question is that if in a truly horrific scenario, how would the villain manage to fight the urge of the super-intelligent organism even though he is being completely controlled and has his entire bodily functions being controlled? Also, what would cause him to make the even more difficult thought of suiciding to help prevent himself from damaging the world?

Edit: Sorry for not clarifying, the limits of the mind-control are so, every few days the host has 30 minutes of free will, mercy on behalf of the organism, this does have limitations though, if he communicates about his situation to anyone else he will die and the organism will transmit itself to the person who he tried to convey it to, if it was long distance as such in a phone call than the organism will just take control again and not give him any free will ever. This also relates to any other action that puts the organism at risk. The only way the organism can transfer is touch, so that means that if the host dies, it dies. During his free will periods, the host does think of committing suicide but is afraid of losing all free will because he knows that the organism will stop him. His means? Well there are never too many ways to kill yourself, the only thing stopping him is the organism. And about the part of the story-based question I understand I could have phrased it better and just want to understand if there is a loophole around full mind-control.

Comment: Depends.  What are the limits of the mind-control?  Does he even think of committing suicide?  Does he have any means to commit it?

Comment: This is a story-based question about character motivation, which makes it off topic for this site, more suited to WritingSE.  The only potentially objectively answerable element is about how to resist the "call" of the organism, but with no information on the organism or even how it is calling there is no way to advise on a defence.

Comment: I'm just going to throw it a random recurrence in many fantasy genres that include mind readers and manipulators, which I'm also relying on in my world. Most of the time the issue of mind control doesn't revolve strictly on a master-slave relationship but rather on a gap in willpower, characters who are strong-minded are able to intrude the minds of the weak-minded to probe and influence them, ultimately assuming direct mind-control over them if the willpower differential is large enough between the two.

Comment: Better edit this, or put a second topic about this creature itself. I wonder why this mighty superior organism, able to remotely check a victim's phone record, would be so afraid of being discovered... Does its design have shortcomings/vulnerabilities it has to hide ? Or is it stupid and does it just take over any mind that comes near ? Maybe these shortcomings would give a clue to answer the above question.

Answer (score 3):

## food, sickness and drugs

Mind control is extremely difficult. Any action is dictated nor only by the brain, but a host of moderators as well. Hormones come not just from the brain, but the gut, liver and other parts as well. We can see that gut flora and fauna has a way of releasing hormones that can help with identifying certain foods and then motivating someone to get this food. That helps the flora and fauna that is currently occupying the gut most. Sickness can also influence behaviour, like rabies makimg people avoid water.

Your organism needs to be able to control the brain and preferably the body in an incredibly complex way. Any changes in food intake, or even just bring hungry, can already cause differences that are difficult to accommodate for. I understand the question says full control, but can it prevent a very hungry man from not eating? Maybe it can, but it will probably get progressively difficult.

Changing eating habbits might be difficult and not quick enough. You only have half an hour per day to stuff yourself. Certainly not impossible to change your habbits in half an hour a day, but not quick enough. Getting sick might also be difficult. At best you can walk half an hour in busy streets to catch something, as the organism probably doesn't allow direct risky behaviour.

So let's entertain ourselves.

Drugs are incredibly powerful in modifying behaviour and done as entertainment. It can look relatively innocent with even coffee, but caffeine modifies behaviour not just in being more awake. Alcohol is technically a hard drug in how radically it changes behaviour. These are often seen as harmless and recreational, while already impacting you a ton. Add cocain, heroin, LSD or similar and you have powerful behaviour modifying tools at your disposal. Too bad Overdosing is probably not allowed by the organism, but you might get there if it loses control. Still it's a dangerous bid, as you only have half an hour to do it right and likely only one shot.

Now mix them.

Drugs are incredibly dangerous when mixing them. Each can mess with the supports of the mind. If a single support is removed it's most often fine. If you start taking other drugs that mess with other supports at the same time it can all come crashing down. I've seen a relatively harmless amount of alcohol and space cake turn into a full blown psychosis where time was flowing backwards and forwards, we were all imposters from a different dimension and twice he tried to get out of the window (4th floor). Once because it was a good idea and once to get back to his own dimension.

If you mix stringer sfuff this can get worse, to even permanent damage. Could a super intelligent mind controlling being control a person high on crystal meth and LSD? Can the organism itself handle it, as it would get affected by any drugs the host takes? It might be toxic for all we know.

I would entertain myself. You might be able to get an addiction for both the host and the organism. You might get permanent damage, hampering the organism, or simply overdose. There is a good chance the organism can't control the host when on drugs, widening the window to do crazy stuff. It all starts with an innocent recreational drive.